# word count textarea jquery script initial text count onload issue

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, count, words

I'm using a word count textarea jquery script and I'm trying to work out how to update the word count onload to e.g. 2 from the preset text area "this example" to start with.

(it currently shows 0)

I can set the focus on it and move the cursor but I don't know how to update it initially, any ideas?

HTML

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jQuery.textareaCounter.c.js"></script> 

<textarea id="txtarea" name="text" rows="7" cols="120">this example</textarea>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $("textarea").textareaCounter();
    document.getElementById('txtarea').focus();
    var val = document.getElementById('txtarea').value; //store the value of the element
    document.getElementById('txtarea').value = ''; //clear the value of the element
    document.getElementById('txtarea').value = val; //set that value back. so cursor is at end.
</script>
```

jquery.min.js contains:-

```
(function(a){a.fn.textareaCounter=function(b){var c={limit:10};var b=a.extend(c,b);return this.each(function(){var c,d,e,f;c=a(this);c.after('<span style="font-size: 11px; clear: both; margin-top: 3px; display: block;" id="counter-text">Max. '+b.limit+" words</span>");c.keyup(function(){d=c.val();if(d===""){e=0}else{e=a.trim(d).split(" ").length}if(e>b.limit){a("#counter-text").html('<span style="color: #DD0000;">0 words left</span>');f=a.trim(d).split(" ",b.limit);f=f.join(" ");a(this).val(f)}else{a("#counter-text").html(b.limit-e+" words left")}})})}})(jQuery)
```

jQuery.textareaCounter.c.js contains:-

```
(function(a) {
    a.fn.textareaCounter = function(b) {
        var c = {
            limit: 10
        };
        var b = a.extend(c, b);
        return this.each(function() {
            var c, d, e, f;
            c = a(this);
            c.after('<span style="font-size: 11px; clear: both; margin-top: 3px; display: block;" id="counter-text">' + "0 words</span>");
            c.keyup(function() {
                d = c.val();
                if (d === "") {
                    e = 0
                } else {
                    e = d.replace(/^[\s,.;]+/, "").replace(/[\s,.;]+$/, "").split(/[\s,.;]+/).length;
                }
                if (e > b.limit) {
                    // a("#counter-text").html('<span style="color: #DD0000;">0 words left</span>');
                    // f=a.trim(d).split(" ",b.limit);
                    // f=f.join(" ");
                    // a(this).val(f)
                    a("#counter-text").html(e + " words ")
                    document.myform.numwords.value = e;
                } else {
                    a("#counter-text").html(e + " words ")
                    document.myform.numwords.value = e;
                }
            });
        });
    }
})
(jQuery)
```

Comment: ok, but now the <input type="hidden" name="numwords" value="0"> isn't been updated.

Comment: <input type="hidden" name="numwords" value="javascript:numwords"> seems to set it to inital value correctly.

Answer (score 1):

This is what I changed in *jQuery.textareaCounter.c.js*:

```
var initCount = c.text().split(" ").length;
if(initCount < 2){initCount=0;}
c.after('<span style="font-size: 11px; clear: both; margin-top: 3px; display: block;" id="counter-text">' + initCount +" words</span>");
```

[Here is the **JSFiddle** demo](http://jsfiddle.net/anoorally/v3cuqhw0/)

Comment: @user3725395 Please do mark this as answer (the tick below the vote button) if it resolved your problem. Thanx :)

Answer (score 0):

You can fire a `keyup` event during initialization to trigger the update:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $("textarea").textareaCounter();
    document.getElementById('txtarea').focus();
    var val = document.getElementById('txtarea').value; //store the value of the element
    document.getElementById('txtarea').value = ''; //clear the value of the element
    document.getElementById('txtarea').value = val; //set that value back. so cursor is at end.

    // init word count
    $("textarea")[0].dispatchEvent(new Event('keyup'));
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

//Function to show maxlength of Textarea

```
document.getElementById("textArea").addEventListener("keyup",function(){

    var textAreaValue = document.getElementById("textArea").value;
    var show = (250 - (textAreaValue.length));
    document.getElementById('count').innerHTML = show + " characters remaining";
});
```